# Query an array based on multiple conditions

Tags: arrays, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, mongorepository

I have this Array

```
    "food": [
    {
        "id": "2023",
        "type": "mexican",
    },
    {
        "id": "2023",
        "type": "italian",
    },
     {
        "id": "2024",
        "type": "chinese",
    }]
```

I created this Query:

```
@Query(value = "{$and: [{'dependencies.id' : ?0}, {'dependencies.type': ?1}]}",
Optional<Food> findByIdAndType(String id, String type);
```

If I give these values:

```
id = 2023, type = mexican
```

I am getting this result:

```
    "food": [
    {
        "id": "2023",
        "type": "mexican",
    },
    {
        "id": "2023",
        "type": "italian",
    }]
```

Is not working properly because I want to have just the elements within the array food, where the id and the type are equal to the input. For the example, I am expecting to have:

```
    "food": [
    {
        "id": "2023",
        "type": "mexican",
    }]
```

I do not know how can I query each element of my array

Answer (score 0):

The `$and` operator will return true if there is at least one element in array where `id = 2023` and `type = mexican`. But these do not need to be the same element.
To find one element that matches both conditions, use `$elemMatch`.

```
{
  "food": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "id": 0,
      "type": "mexican"
    }
  }
}
```

The returning document will contain the entire array, not just the matched element. To return only the required item from the array use `$` operator in `projection`.

```
{
  "food.$": 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is not clear where I should add the food.$: 1. Should I add this within the first part? With $elemMatch I am still getting all the array

Comment: `food.$: 1` is the projection. It is not a part of the query filter. Check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-projections-aggregations#2-projections-using-mongorepository) for an example of using projection with Spring Data @Query